# Map fetch/result from jooq to specific Record

Tags: java, casting, jooq

When I currently query with Jooq I am explicitly casting each record-object to the expected record-type.

```
Result<Record> result = sql.select().from(Tables.COUNTRY).fetch();
for (Record r : result) {
    CountryRecord countryRecord = (CountryRecord) r;
    //Extract data from countryRecord
    countryRecord.getId();
}
```

Is it, with Jooq, possibly to cast the result straight into the desired record-type?

Such as (this does not compile):

```
Result<CountryRecord> countryRecords = (Result<CountryRecord>) sql.select().from(Tables.COUNTRY).fetch();
for (CountryRecord cr : countryRecords) {
    cr.getNamet();
    //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the `select().from(...)` syntax when you want to fetch generated record types. Use `selectFrom()` instead. This is documented here:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-execution/fetching/record-vs-tablerecord

So your query should be:

```
Result<CountryRecord> countryRecords = sql.selectFrom(Tables.COUNTRY).fetch();
for (CountryRecord cr : countryRecords) {
    cr.getNamet();
    //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

@Lukas,

Actually we are using `fetchInto()` to convert the results to list of object.

For example:

`Employee` pojo matching database table is employee.

```
List<Employee> employeeList = sql.select(Tables.Employee)
                                 .from(Tables.EMPLOYEE).fetchInto(Employee.class);
```

similarly, how could we convert the records we are fetching using joins?

For example:

`Customer` pojo matching database table is `customer`.

`Employee` pojo matching database table is `employee`.

```
sql.select(<<IWantAllFields>>).from(Tables.CUSTOMER)
                              .join(Tables.EMPLOYEE)
                              .on(Tables.EMPLOYEE.ID.equal(Tables.CUSTOMER.EMPLOYEE_ID))
                              .fetchInto(?);
```

Comment: you can use the newRecord method to define fields that all you want. The follow demo code snippet  link is:  
https://gist.github.com/Q10Viking/93d3e4e96afbe739c811025c1a873588